# Autocompletion textbox html

Tags: javascript, php, html, autocomplete

I am working in web page that can support autocomplition more times. If I write d , program will offer me dari. Ok, but I want be able to put more then one text in textbox. So I press ; and I start write new input and program offer me again good, but he delete previous option. 
index.html

```
<title>Auto Complete Input box</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        //selectFirst: true
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Tag:</label>
<input name="tag" type="text" id="tag" size="150"/>
</body>
</html>
```

autocomplete.php

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET['q'];
 $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);

 $my_data2=$my_data;
 $pos=0;
 for($i=0;$i<strlen($my_data);++$i)
 {
   if($my_data[$i]==';')$pos=$i;
 }

 $s="";
 if($pos!=0){
 for($i=$pos+1;$i<strlen($my_data);++$i)$s.=$my_data[$i];
 $my_data=$s;}

 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','raspored') or die("Database Error");
 $sql="SELECT ime FROM korisnici WHERE ime LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY ime";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

 if($result)
 {
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo $row['ime']."\n";
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: for autocomplete data must be in format of array of label and value .. other wise u have to map them using $.map

Answer (score 0):

You have to `extend the autocomplete plugin` to get this.

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/sgxKJ/)